# Oracle sql script to number record by group by fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to number each result record by my group by fields, I've tried the following by it just numbers every row sequentially.

```
select rownum, field_1, field_2, field_2
from table1
where field_1 = 726200783
group by rownum, field_1, field_2, field_2
order by field_1, field_2, field_2, rownum
```

the result I receive is:

```
ROWNUM  field_1       field_1     field_1 
4       726200783     C           236332639   
1       726200783     C           236361290   
2       726200783     N           235814367   
3       726200783     P           235843569
```

But I want to do the following, so that I can then filter by specific row value, eg. where rownum = 1

```
ROWNUM  field_1       field_2     field_3 
1       726200783     C           236361290 
2       726200783     C           236332639    
1       726200783     N           235814367   
1       726200783     P           235843569
```

Comment: Well, you just can't have three rows 1. You sure the desired output is correct ?

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there a way to get my desired output? I just used rownum in my script as an example.

Comment: Ok so let's call the rownumber column as your "custom classifier". What would classify a row as 1 or 2 ? I didn't get from the example.

Comment: The "custom classifier" is just numbering the records where field_1, field_2 are the same and there are multiple values for field_3, then "custom classifier" is numbering based on field_3 lowest value to highest value.

Comment: Oh well, you are ranking over a field_1, field_2 partition ordered by field 3 desc :)

`SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY field_1, field_2 ORDER BY field_3 DESC)
    field_1, field_2, field_3
 FROM table1
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to rank values over a ordered partition.

This is the query you want

```
SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY field_1, field_2 ORDER BY field_3 DESC)     
    field_1, field_2, field_3  
FROM table1
```

A partition is a group of the exactly same values (from one or more columns) in a table.

The OVER() defines the window that your window function will be applied to. You control the window by partitioning and ordering.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use ROW_NUMBER() analytic function instead of ROWNUM pseudo column:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3) AS
        (
            Select 726200783, 'C', 236332639 From Dual Union All
            Select 726200783, 'C', 236361290 From Dual Union All
            Select 726200783, 'N', 235814367 From Dual Union All
            Select 726200783, 'P', 235843569  From Dual
        )
Select    Row_Number() OVER(Partition By FIELD_1, FIELD_2 Order By FIELD_1, FIELD_2) "RN",
          FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3
From      tbl
Order By  FIELD_1, FIELD_2

        RN    FIELD_1 FIELD_2    FIELD_3
---------- ---------- ------- ----------
         1  726200783 C        236332639 
         2  726200783 C        236361290 
         1  726200783 N        235814367 
         1  726200783 P        235843569
```